# Laplace equation on infinite strip

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem using the Fourier transform:

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$ on the domain $\;0\lt y\lt b$ , $-\infty\lt x \lt \infty
 \;$ with the following conditions:

$$ u(x,0)= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{for }-a< x<a\\
0 & \text{for}\; \; \; | x |>a\\
\end{cases} $$
$$u(x,b)=0, \ -\infty\lt x \lt \infty $$
So, here's what I tried:
First, I took the Fourier transform of  in the $x$ variable, and the problem now looks like this:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \hat{u}(\omega,y)}{\partial y^2}-{\omega}^2\hat{u}(\omega,y)=0 $$
With the conditions:
$$\hat{u}(\omega,0)=\frac{2\sin{\omega a}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\omega}\ \ \ \text{and}  \; \;\hat{u}(\omega,b)=0 $$
Note that I'm using the following definitions for the Fourier transform and its inverse:
$$ {\mathscr{F}}[f(x)]= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega x}f(x)\,dx \;,\;\; {\mathscr{F}}^{-1}[\hat{f}(\omega)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i\omega x}\hat{f}(\omega)\,d\omega$$
Then, I solved the second order equation for $\hat{u}(\omega,y)$, which has the solution:
$$ \hat{u}(\omega,y)=Ae^{\omega y}+Be^{-\omega y} $$
Using the boundary conditions I found that:
$$ A+B =\frac{2\sin{\omega a}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\omega} \\Ae^{2\omega b} + B=0 $$
Now, here's where I'm stuck. The problem says that I need to establish a "bounding condition". So, the condition I proposed was that $u(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \pm
\infty $ . My question is: does this condition carry on to $\hat{u}$?  i.e. Must $\hat{u}(\omega,y)$ vanish as $ \omega \rightarrow \pm
\infty$?
I don't really know what to do from here on or whether I'm on the right track. Any help would be appreciated!